# How to get submitButton to not take effect until after the initial loading of the R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, submit-button

I have a Shiny app that has widgets which control the out of a map.

There are several inputs.

I don't want the map to reload until the user has edited all of the inputs they want to edit.

Hence I have this line of code:

```
        submitButton("Update Map", icon("refresh"))
```

in my UI, which only reloads the map if the user press on the button.

But now it won't load the initial map upon the launching of the app.

I want that behavior.

What do I need to change?

Comment: You can try and make use of the `actionButton()`. For instance, when it returns value `0`, you show your initial map. Else call a `eventReactive()` function, which will be triggered every time the value of `actionButton()` changes. Within that function just place your map processing and related output.

Comment: can you share a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your app exhibiting the loading issue? without that it is just a guessing game

Comment: Does your server.R include ‘session’?

Comment: @BuffsGrad16 no